# Update postgres/postgis point data attribute from another enclosed polygon shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I have

1. a placename **point table in postgis** with 'district' column.
2. a districts **polygon shapefile** with district name in 'Name' column.
   See the image below.

I would like to update the 'district' columns(in placename psql table) with the corresponding district name from the shapefile polygons in which ***each placename point feature reside***.

How can I do this in QGIS? 
Or Is there any other way?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Postgis way : (import polygon shape to postgis using shp2psql )

```
UPDATE points SET district = poly.district FROM poly WHERE ST_Within(points.geom, poly.geom)
```

see [ST_Within](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-21/.ST_Within.html)

and i cant remember easy QGIS way , but its possible

Comment: Can we update multiple columns in single update query? like, "province" also..

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html

UPDATE points SET (district, province) = (poly.district, poly.province) FROM poly WHERE ST_Within(points.geom, poly.geom)

That may work , didn't test. But it should be possible.

Comment: Should I use any EPSG codes? If, yes, how? Point geom is in 900913. And poly geom does not show any.

Comment: both need to be in same system (ST_SetSrid(geom, srid) can be used to set srid and ST_Transform(geom,srid ) can be used to transform to different projection

Comment: should I add this along with the update query?

Comment: Not  really, that should be done on importin data phase. 
UPDATE xx set geom on = ST_SetSRID(4326) ( 4326 is wgs84 , you should use correct srid ) 
now both data needs to be on same srid then UPDATE xx set geom = ST_Transform(geom, 900973) or you can also do transform  in where clause if you really need to have data in different srid  ´WHERE ST_Within(points.geom, ST_Transform(poly.geom,900973))´